# How to streaming delivery large binary content with ML Xquery RESTful API

Tags: streaming, xquery, marklogic

Below is an blog post taking out how to use [ML nodejs api to handle stream binary file](https://www.marklogic.com/blog/nodejs-api-binary-documents/).
[image]

I am for the similar thing with ML XQuery RESTful API code sample to perform the same thing.

Currently I use `xs:base64Binary(xs:hexBinary(fn:doc($documentUri)))` before return the WEB API response `map:put($responseObj, 'document', $pdfData)`.

The above solution works for small size binary file. However if the binary file is big, time out error may happen. I believe the `xs:base64Binary` may require loading all the binary content in memory first. That could be the bottleneck of the problem.

Currently we do not use ML Nodejs. How to do with ML XQuery RESTful API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MarkLogic will chunk binary content from the modules database (static content).

If the content is in the content database, you need to chunk it in your application code. There is a sample here: https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/binaries#id_76113

Separately, and just for reference to your thoughts of it loading into memory, it may be useful to read up on the three ways binary content can be stored. The memory and cache requirements differs per approach. Just good background reading : https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/binaries#id_93203